# Removing horizontal space before a chapter name

Tags: spacing, chapters, titlesec

I want remove the white space before the chapter name, however, the white space is different in different sections of the document.

```
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-40pt}{0pt}
```

[image]

[image]

```
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{-20pt}{-40pt}{0pt}
```

[image]

[image]

Below is a short working example that shows what I mean.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{}{20pt}{\Huge}   
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-40pt}{0pt} % This is the line which I am using. I don't know if it is the right one to use.

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Share\LaTeX}
\lhead{Guides and tutorials}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{fancy}

\clearpage

\chapter{Specs}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

I would appreciate any help in fixing this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) provides the following format for `\titleformat` (see section **3.1 Format**):

```
\titleformat{<command>}
  [<shape>]
  {<format>}
  {<label>}
  {<sep>}
  {<before-code>}
  [<after-code>]
```

where

> `<sep>` is the horizontal separation between label and title body and must be a length (it must not be empty). This space is vertical in `display` `<shape>`; in frame it is the distance from text to frame. Both `<label>` and `<sep>` are ignored in starred versions of sectioning commands. If you are using
>   picture and the like, set this parameter to `0pt`.

Your **Contents** chapter is set using `\chapter*`, and is therefore without number. Since you're not setting numbers for numbered chapters (`<label>` is left *empty*), you'll have to use a `0pt` `<sep>`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-40pt}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage

\chapter{Specs}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```